# "word counts to stay within"

Tags: grammar

[Which, believe me, is frustrating when you have word counts to stay within.](http://www.theguardian.com/media/mind-your-language/2014/jan/31/mind-your-language-no-english-words)

*Word counts to stay within* makes no sense to me. Am I dealing with an idiom here? Because if I am, I would like to know which that idiom is. Hard as I tried, I could find no such idiom anywhere I could look it up in.

Comment: Would 'within which to stay' be more comprehensible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Word counts to stay within* is an example of a construction called a [***Relative Infinitive***](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a15299%20%22relative%20infinitive%22).
That means it's a relative clause, but instead of being a **tensed** relative clause, it's an infinitive.

Relative infinitives can be converted to tensed relative claues, but they always have some deontic  modal involved (like *must, should, have to, ought to*).

- *the man to do the job = the man that/who **should** do the job*
- *the man to see = the man that/who one **ought to** see*
- *the rope to pull on = the rope that/which one **has to** pull on*
- *page limits to stay within = page limits that/which one **must** stay within*

It's a sneaky way to put a modal meaning into a sentence without actually using a modal.

Comment: A relative infinitive is a term to conjure with.

Answer (score 3):

To me more than an idiom, that sounds like a perfect sentence.

While the context could have helped more, however my interpretation of this sentence is - "It is frustrating when I have a word limitation to stick to."

This means that the speaker is talking about a situation wherein he is supposed to limit his expression (either in written or oral) within a specific count of words. He may have more to say / write but the word limit restriction is not allowing him to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would word it as 'it's frustrating when I have to stay within the word count/limit.'

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous to me.  "Word counts to stay within" could express a minimum, a maximum, or a range.